# IIS URL Rewrite Rule with Params

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am having a hard time getting a URL rewrite rule to work.

I want this url:

`http://www.mysite.com/oldpage.aspx?oldid=123`

To rewrite to:

`http://www.mysite.com/sub/newpage.aspx?newid=123`

Here is what I have, but it's not working:

```
<rule name="Old2New" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^oldpage.aspx?oldid=([0-9]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" 
            url="/sub/newpage.aspx?newid={R:1}" 
            appendQueryString="true"  />
</rule>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?  There is a huge difference from .NET 4 to previous versions (in previous versions, URL rewriting sucked, frankly).

Comment: @pearcewg - actually, UrlRewrite is a function/extension of IIS and really has nothing to do with which version of ASP.NET you're running. I think you're mistaking this for the various bodges you had to do on IIS6 (wild card mapping, httpmodules etc) if you didn't have an proper ISAPI based rewriter such as ISAPI_Rewrite or the Iconic Rewriter.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to the question mark. If I escape it by changing the matchURL to "^oldpage.aspx\?oldid=([0-9]+)", the test match seems to work, but requests through IIS are not getting rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

Use the conditions to catch the query string part {C:1}, like this:

```
<rule name="My rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^oldpage\.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="oldid=([0-9]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/sub/newpage.aspx?newid={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

The regex index starts at 0 not 1. so your rule should be:

```
<rule name="Old2New" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^oldpage.aspx?oldid=([0-9]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" 
            url="/sub/newpage.aspx?newid={R:0}" 
            appendQueryString="true"  />
</rule>
```

You can easily test your rule in IIS7 interface.

Comment: Actually {R:0} returns "oldpage.aspx?oldid=123", and {R:1} returns 123.  It looks like the problem related to the question mark.